# Java using generics to get list of all Instances

Tags: java

I have a static class with some static members:

```
public static class Foo {
private static Bar one = new Bar();
private static Bar two = new Bar();
private static Bar three = new Bar();
...
private static Bar n = new Bar();
}
```

I want to have method which returns all `Bar`:

`public static List<Bar> getBars()`

Can you tell me how to get all Instances using Java generics?

Comment: Generics wouldn't help you here.  You're not even putting them into a list to begin with.

Comment: Why are you breaking these out into all these separately named Bars to begin with? They should all just be put into a list so that you can have as many as you want. Also not sure why you are using a static class if you are going to have all of these variables?

Comment: If you post what you are trying to do I can help you design it better but this doesn't make much sense as you are doing it now

Comment: because I want to reference them in other classes like `return Foo.one`

Comment: I understand the question and I can understand why you might want to use something like this, but please have a look at the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If you describe more what you want, we can help you better, for example by suggesting enums or reflection

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking something like a modified version of the type safe enum pattern?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TypeSafeEnum{
    private String data=null;
    private static List<TypeSafeEnum> list=new ArrayList<>();
    private TypeSafeEnum(String data){
        this.data=data;
        list.add(this);
    }
    private static TypeSafeEnum One=new TypeSafeEnum("one");
    private static TypeSafeEnum Two=new TypeSafeEnum("two");
    private static TypeSafeEnum Three=new TypeSafeEnum("three");
    private static TypeSafeEnum Four=new TypeSafeEnum("four");
    public String getValue(){
        return data;
    }
    public static List<TypeSafeEnum> getMembers(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

with this you could do something like

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for(TypeSafeEnum member:TypeSafeEnum.getMembers()){
            System.out.println(member.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

and get

```
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
public static List<Bar> getBars(){
    List<Bar> res = new ArrayList<Bar>();
    res.add(one);
    res.add(two);
    ...
    res.add(n);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the `Bar`s in other classes like this: `return Foo.one`